# Selecting ListView in C#

Tags: c#

i have ListView with items 
one ListView with items another one is empty
i need to copy from first ListView selected item to another ListView at the same time
i have to remove the selected item in first ListView in C#

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms or ASP.net?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than removing items from the collection that you're enumerating (as per Wael's answer), which is a "bad idea", use a temporary collection, in this instance a List to store them in before removing them:

```
    List<ListViewItem> itemsToMove = new List<ListViewItem>();
    foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
    {
        itemsToMove.Add(item);
    }
    foreach (ListViewItem item in itemsToMove)
    {
        listView1.Items.Remove(item);
        listView2.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

Where listView1 is the list with the selected items and listView2 is the list to move them to.

Answer (score 0):

this code will copy from the first listview1 to listview2 all the selected items and delete it from listview1

```
    foreach (ListViewItem itm   in ListView1.SelectedItems)
    {
        ListView1.Items.Remove(itm);
        listView2.Items.Add(itm);
    }
```

Comment: Removing items from an enumeration as you're iterating over it isn't a good idea:

http://generally.wordpress.com/2007/10/24/removing-items-in-a-list-while-iterating-through-it/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114735/when-items-change-while-being-enumerated-does-it-affects-the-enumeration

Comment: bad idea to remove items when iterating over them

Comment: sorry I don't know that's it's bad idea to remove items when iterating, thanks for the new info.